# Making an age distribution in netlogo

Tags: distribution, netlogo

I am very new to coding and I am having a bit of trouble. I am trying to make an age distribution in netlogo based off probabilities of having each age at setup.I set up a random-number variable that I am using to aid in the probability.The age probabilities are as follows:

days | probability

```
  _0  ____0.476
 _365__    0.229
 _730    __0.142
_1095   _0.081
_1460    _0.044
_1825    _0.019
_2190   _0.007
_2555  _0.002
```

I also need 2 pDogs to be age 2920

Here is what I have so far, but I'm not sure if there is a better way to do this.

```
    pDogs-own[family age health random-number]

    ask pDogs [
    set random-number random 1000.5]

    ask pDogs
    [if random-number <= 476 [set age 0]]
    ask pDogs
    [if ((random-number > 476) and (random-number <= 705)) [set age 365]] 
    ask pDogs
    [if ((random-number > 705) and (random-number <= 847)) [set age 730]]
    ask pDogs
    [if ((random-number > 847) and (random-number <= 928)) [set age 1095]]
    ask pDogs
    [if ((random-number > 928) and (random-number <= 972)) [set age 1460]]
    ask pDogs
    [if ((random-number > 972) and (random-number <= 991)) [set age 1825]]
    ask pDogs
    [if ((random-number > 991) and (random-number <= 998)) [set age 2190]]
    ask pDogs
    [if ((random-number > 998) and (random-number <= 1000)) [set age 2555]]
```

I am also trying another way to accomplish the same thing. First, I ask 2619 pDogs to be age = 0. I am trying to make a code that says:

```
    ask n-of 2619 pDogs [
    set age 0]
    ask pDogs [
    if age != 0 [
    ask n-of 1262 pDogs [
    set age 365]]]
```

... but its not working.I ultimately want something that I can say that if the age is not one of the previously defined 0, 365, 730, etc. apply the next year/age value.

Comment: So what's the question? Are you just looking for feedback on how to represent this distribution based on what you have now?

Comment: Well, my current code does not give the numbers that I am looking for. The numbers are close, but vary per setup by ~50. I'm looking for a more precise way to have an age distribution. For example: I need 2619 pDogs with age = 0.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See the Lottery example.

Or use Payette's rnd extension:
https://github.com/NetLogo/Rnd-Extension#readme

But if you want exact numbers, as you suggest at the end, you will need a different approach.  For example:

```
turtles-own [age]

to setup
  let _numbers [5 10 15 10 5]
  let _ages [0 1 2 3 4]
  (foreach _ages _numbers [
    let _age ?1
    crt ?2 [set age _age]
  ])
end
```

Comment: Your code excerpt worked well when applied to my model, @Alan. I have one more question about tacking on a death constant at setup. Here's what I have right now, but the death constant is not working as I hoped. Sorry, I'm not very good with formatting.    `let _numbers [ 2619 1262 779 446 243 104 38 9 2]    
  let _ages [0 365 730 1095 1460 1825 2190 2555 2920]   
  let _deaths [476 303 358 392 466 636 750 750 1000]   
  (foreach _ages _numbers _deaths [   
      let _age ?1    
      let _death ?3    
      create-pDogs ?2 [set age _age]     
      ask pDogs [   
        set death _death]])`

Comment: @WilliamBrittainIrick You repeatedly ask all pDogs to reset their death.  Instead, initialize everything at one go: `[set age _age  set death _death]`.  This will apply only to the newly created pDogs.